# Laravel how to get current user position by points

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I wondering how can i get current user position by user points?

Example:

User1 = points: 100
User2 - points: 150
User3 - points: 360

So User 3 will be first, user2 second and etc.

I getting all users by:

```
{{ User::count() }}
```

Users table have a points row.

Any example or help? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can use laravel's Query Builder like following.

`DB::table('users')->orderBy('points', 'desc')->get()`

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by user's points. Eg. User::query()->orderBy('points','DESC')->get();

Edit:

If users table is not so big you can try get all users with row number and then search in collection by points.

DB::statement(DB::raw('set @row:=0'));
$users = User::selectRaw('*, @row:=@row+1 as position')->orderBy('points','DESC')->get();

$points = 150;
$users_by_points  = $users->where('points',$points)->values();

If you have users with same points you can try to group by points + row number.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know how to order. But i need get user position by points :) #2 #4 or #99 like example :)

Comment: Try with 
$position = 4;
User::query()->orderBy('points','DESC')->limit(1)->offset(($position-1))->first();